# Set variable to a sheet's Codename, Using it in the code isn't working

Tags: excel, vba

This works, referring to the codename directly (Sheet3)...

```
Sheet3.Shapes(PopUp).Visible = True
```

...but using a variable set to the same Codename value doesn't...

```
WS = ActiveSheet.CodeName
WS.Shapes(PopUp).Visible = True
```

Why? I ask because I need to extend the larger macro's functionality to the whole workbook, so I'm hoping the variable will let this apply to whatever worksheet the user happens to be on.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Getting a "Compile Error - Invalid Qualifier".  I'm just not yet VBA saavy to solve this.  Also, if this is relevant, I  "Dim WS as String" earlier in the code.

Comment: then just `ActiveSheet.Shapes(PopUp).Visible = True`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see that I needed to be more specific in my setup question. I define both WS and PopUp variables on a sheet's click_event sub. They're supposed to pass to a Code Module sub so that I can use that sub for multiple sheets' click_events.  My 2nd snippet makes it look like both lines are in the same sub.  Sorry.

Comment: might be easier to just use the `Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick` event instead? Otherwise, you can probably pass the sheet object as a parameter to a common method (`Me` can be used instead `Sheet3` in a sheet object module)

Comment: `Worksheet.CodeName` is just a string property, it's metadata that VBA uses to name an automagic project-scope `Workbook` object variable: the whole entire point of using code name is to *avoid* dealing with strings and needing to declare worksheet variables for sheets that already exist at compile-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to [pass a worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807795/set-variable-to-a-sheets-codename-using-it-in-the-code-isnt-working#comment88621475_50807868) and work off that, then *pass a worksheet*:

```
Sub DoSomething(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal popup As String)
    ws.Shapes(popup).Visible = True
End sub
```

And then you can use the *code name* to get the specific worksheet object you want to pass that procedure:

```
DoSomething Sheet1, "shape1"
DoSomething Sheet2, "shape12"
DoSomething Sheet3, "SomeButton"
```

> *I just want a sheet's macro to pass the variables for its Codename*

When used like above, the code name *is* a `Worksheet` variable. VBA uses the string value of the `Worksheet.CodeName` property to generate a project-scoped object variable by that name - and indeed, using these "free" variables whenever you need to refer to any sheet that exists at compile-time, is a thousand times better than dereferencing that exact same object reference through the `Sheets` or `Worksheets` collection using the sheet's `Name`, which your user can change on a whim at any given time (unless workbook structure is protected), and break your code!

---

On the other hand...

> *[...] apply to whatever worksheet the user happens to be on*

This is the textbook definition of `ActiveSheet` - if you need to work on whatever worksheet the user happens to be on, then you use `ActiveSheet`, which refers to exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

If you Dim the variable `ws` as a string, it will not work as a sheet object.

If you have changed the (Name) property of the sheet to "MyCodename", for example, you can just use that codename as the sheet object

`MyCodename.Shapes(PopUp).Visible = True`

.. assuming that the variable `popup` is of the proper type and initialised with the proper value.

Comment: There are 20 sheets in the workbook I want this code to work on, so I hope I can leave the different codenames as they are (Sheet1, Sheet2....Sheet20), and that's why my first snippet works fine. I just want a sheet's macro to pass the variables for its Codename (WS) and active shape (PopUp) -both set in the sheet's macro- to this shared code module. And that's why I need the sheet's Codename to be a variable.  Yes, the variable PopUp works fine.

Comment: @QFarley seems you're confusing `CodeName` (a `String` property of the `Worksheet` class), the "free" object variables VBA creates named as per that property, and `ActiveSheet`. If you need to work off the `ActiveSheet`, then code names are not relevant. the `CodeName` *auto-variables* are extremely useful when you need to refer to a *specific* worksheet that exists at compile-time, but useless when you need to refer to "whatever worksheet the user happens to be on".

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realized ActiveSheet was exactly the variable I wanted in the code. I get it now.  Added ActiveSheet in all instances to my code and it works perfectly.  My issue is Resolved. :)